# Need to use python to pull from svn repository

Tags: python, svn, jar

I have an SVN repository
(Example:
http://test.google.com/svn/hussam/)
It has files I would like to checkout to directory in Linux
(Example: /home/hussam/shared/)

What command should I use?

Comment: What have you tried or researched so far?

Answer (score 0):

Probably simplest is to use subprocess.Popen or subprocess.call to call the svn commands, that you would call from command line.